# Tweepy + Twitter API v2: I want to extract the tweet.id for media_key only

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

What if I want to take the Tweet ID and `media_keys` and only get the Tweet ID that has `media_keys`?

I was trying to do it with this sample but I got stuck:
https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/examples.html

```
client = tweepy.Client(consumer_key=API_KEY, consumer_secret=API_SECRET, access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN, access_token_secret=ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, bearer_token=Bearer_token)

counts = 10

search_result = client.get_list_tweets(id='list id', max_results=counts, expansions=["attachments.media_keys"])
tweets = search_result.data

includes = search_result.includes
medias = includes['media']

for tweetid in tweets:
    tid = tweetid.id

mediass = {media['media_key']: media for media in medias}
for tweet in tweets:
    print(tweet.id, mediass)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the `attachments` field of [Tweet objects](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/data-dictionary/object-model/tweet) to obtain media keys for media attached to the Tweet.